# jQuery append element duplicates itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, append

I have my alert box that appears on every CRUD operation.

```
<section class="content container-fluid">
        <div id="notif-box" style="display: none;" class="alert alert-dismissible">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 id="head-title"><i id="icon-box" class="icon fa"></i></h4>
            <span id="alert-message"></span>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I have problem with #head-title where I write headText.

In my methods on success I call:

```
displayNotif('danger', 'check', 'User added successfully', 'Success!');
```

and this fucntion:

```
function displayNotif(type, icon, text, alertTitle) {

   $("#notif-box").removeClass();
   $("#icon-box").removeClass();
   $("#head-title").removeClass(alertTitle);
   $("#notif-box").show();
   var notifBoxClass = "alert alert-"+type+" alert-dismissible";
   var iconClass = "icon fa fa-"+icon;
   $("#notif-box").addClass(notifBoxClass);
   $("#icon-box").addClass(iconClass);

  // this is the issue
  $("#head-title").append(alertTitle);

  $("#alert-message").html(text);
   setTimeout(function () {
    $("#notif-box").fadeOut();
}, 5000);
```

}

When I hit first time add button, head title is 'Success!'
When hit second time head title is 'Succsss!Success'!
Third is ''Success!Success!Success!'

Other elements work as expected! Can not figure where the problem is!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending again and again, simply replacing the text should solve the issue.

Change

```
$("#head-title").append(alertTitle);
```

To

```
$("#head-title").html(alertTitle);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Problem is that when I change like that the icon is missing than. I don't know why is disappearing in that case? @Mamun